# Customizing class to elicit certain irb behavior

Tags: ruby

I've created a class called SpecialArray and I'd like to customize what sort of output irb shows.  When I create an instance variable, test_array, and generate an array using SpecialArray, and I type "test_array" into irb, I get this:

```
1.9.3p194 :051 > test_array
=> [1, 2, 0, 6, 11]
```

And when I use "puts", irb just returns the object, like so:

```
1.9.3p194 :054 > puts test_array
#<SpecialArray:0x007ff05d0b4960>
```

But I'd like to have irb behave more like the first example, where I only typed "test_array: (i.e. I'd like to return the array in a single line).  I tried overriding the default puts method with my own, but without much success. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You could have asked that in the previous question. Unlike `p` and default IRB behavior, `puts` calls `to_s` method of the object to get its string representation. Override it in your class the way you like and that's it. And what you need for a good indentation on StackOverflow is 4 spaces. Not more, not less.

Comment: Because that's what your `SpecialArray#to_s` returns. You should override it to get a nicer result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test_array is an object and when calling puts directly on the object will generally return you the instance.

You should be using the following in your puts method:

```
puts test_array.to_s
```